# Convert list to string inPython

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have following code

```
round_subset_list = subset.round(2).values.tolist() 
print(round_subset_list)
```

The result is

```
[0.47, -0.36, -0.5, 0.2, 0.35, 1.82, -0.78, -0.91, 0.36, -1.74, 0.24, 0.76, 0.57, 2.32, 1.55, -1.31, -0.09, -0.02, -0.07, -0.19, -0.25, -1.09, 0.64, 1.22, -0.56, 1.76, 0.13, 1.33, -0.74, -1.15, 1.63, 1.04, -0.26, 0.02, -1.2, 0.37, 0.43, 0.04, 1.34, 0.57, 0.76, -1.25, -0.05, 0.12, 0.8, -0.99, -0.11, -0.54, -0.08, -0.04, -0.76, -0.8, 0.35, 1.54, -0.99, -0.35, -0.28, 0.45, -0.04, -0.06, 0.02, 0.58, -0.32, -0.1, 0.28, 0.3, -0.36, 0.81, 0.79, 0.21, 1.81, 0.19, 0.84, 0.2, -0.06, -0.11, -1.4, -2.08, 0.88, -0.14, -0.96, 1.3, 0.06, -0.37, 1.49, -0.91, 1.14, -1.05, 1.49, -0.79, 2.02, 0.38, 2.4, 1.25, 0.5, 1.11, -0.54, -0.1, 0.63, 1.01]
```

I wanna convert them into something look like `['0.47', '-0.36', '-0.5', '0.2', ...]`

```
subset.string = ''.join(str(e) for e in round_subset_list)
print(subset.string)
```

The above code doesn't work

Comment: By “doesn’t work”, do you mean your PC catches fire?

Comment: ```print([str(i) for i in e])```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
round_subset_list = [str(i) for i in round_subset_list]
```

Comment: IMO, rather than reusing the same variable for lists of different data types, a different variable should be used. Python doesn’t care about types, but it’s helpful to humans reading the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the map fuction.

```
round_subset_list = [0.47, -0.36, -0.5, 0.2, 0.35, 1.82, -0.78, -0.91, 0.36, -1.74, 0.24, 0.76, 0.57, 2.32, 1.55, -1.31, -0.09, -0.02, -0.07, -0.19, -0.25, -1.09, 0.64, 1.22, -0.56, 1.76, 0.13, 1.33, -0.74, -1.15, 1.63, 1.04, -0.26, 0.02, -1.2, 0.37, 0.43, 0.04, 1.34, 0.57, 0.76, -1.25, -0.05, 0.12, 0.8, -0.99, -0.11, -0.54, -0.08, -0.04, -0.76, -0.8, 0.35, 1.54, -0.99, -0.35, -0.28, 0.45, -0.04, -0.06, 0.02, 0.58, -0.32, -0.1, 0.28, 0.3, -0.36, 0.81, 0.79, 0.21, 1.81, 0.19, 0.84, 0.2, -0.06, -0.11, -1.4, -2.08, 0.88, -0.14, -0.96, 1.3, 0.06, -0.37, 1.49, -0.91, 1.14, -1.05, 1.49, -0.79, 2.02, 0.38, 2.4, 1.25, 0.5, 1.11, -0.54, -0.1, 0.63, 1.01]

print(list(map(str, round_subset_list)))
```